# wrapping long axis labels

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'd like to have wrapped labels for categories. Plotly is displaying spaces where I want line breaks. When the strings get too long it just displays them at a 45 degree angle.

```
 plot_ly(x =c("this\nand\nthat\nand\nall\nof\nthe\nthings",
 "the\nother\nstring\nthat\nmakes\nthis\nway\ntoo\nlong"), 
 y = c(1,2), name = "testing",type = "bar")
```

I'm using Shiny / R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend wrapping the strings in the data frame first. So if your data frame is

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("this\nand\nthat\nand\nall\nof\nthe\nthings",
                       "the\nother\nstring\nthat\nmakes\nthis\nway\ntoo\nlong"), 
                 y = c(1, 2))
```

Then wrap the strings with HTML line breaks at some sensible interval.

```
df$wrappedx <- sapply(df$x, 
                      FUN = function(x) {paste(strwrap(x, width = 16), collapse = "<br>")})
```

And then use that column instead. You may need to increase the margin at the bottom (in pixels).

```
plot_ly(data = df, 
        x = wrappedx,
        y = y,
        name = "testing",
        type = "bar") %>%
    layout(margin = list(b = 70))
```

In summary, `\n` in strings are ignored in HTML so line breaks are `<br>`.

Comment: "In summary, \n in strings are ignored in HTML so line breaks are <br>" perfect! already made a string chopper so just subbed the <br> in

Comment: the margin increase is helpful too! Although I'd recommend making it a function of the longest label in the graph, rather than a constant.
With a little experimentation, at least for Courier New, monospace, the formula is `(5/4 * fontSize * max(linesOfText))` pixels

Comment: Nice idea to make a margin size function. I'm sure to find that useful.